# Sql group by addition

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have a query where i pull all the records of a 'consultant' with a 'marketing_fee'. the results are like below :

[image]

Is there a way to group them by Consultant (the middle column) but add up all of the marketing_fee's?

The code I'm using at the moment just gets the latest fees.

```
select a.marketing_fee, v.Consultant, user.colorcode 
from valuations v 
join status_history sh on sh.ref = v.Ref 
join user on user.username = v.Consultant 
join answer a on a.title = v.Ref 
where sh.status = 'booked' and sh.date between '2016-09-07 23:59:00' and '2016-09-14 23:59:00'
```

Comment: Yes, you can use aggregation with grouping.  What seems to be a problem?

Comment: i want to group by consultant but add all of the fees not sure how that could be possible

Comment: Have you ever used `SUM()` with `GROUP BY`?

Comment: can u give a sample output. I dont undrtand ur problem

Comment: NAME1
450
#cc7a00
NAME1
1500
#cc7a00
NAME1
900
#cc7a00
NAME2
11980
#009933
NAME2
NULL
#000000
NAME2
10
#000000
NAME3
500
#4d4d4d
NAME3
NULL
#009973
NAME3
1200
#9b0b60
NAME3
3000
#9b0b60
NAME3
NULL
#0066ff
NAME3
400
#0066ff
NAME3
650
#0066ff

Comment: Still multiple consultants

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
select v.Consultant, sum(a.marketing_fee)
from valuations v join
     status_history sh
     on sh.ref = v.Ref join
     user on user.username = v.Consultant join
     answer a on a.title = v.Ref 
where sh.status = 'booked' and
      sh.date between '2016-09-07 23:59:00' and '2016-09-14 23:59:00'
group by v.Consultant;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with the below query.

```
   select SUM(IFNULL(a.marketing_fee,0))Marketing_Fee,
               v.Consultant,
               User.Colorcode
    from valuations v 
        join status_history sh
              on sh.ref = v.Ref 
        join user on user.username = v.Consultant
        join answer a on a.title = v.Ref 
   where sh.status = 'booked' and
  sh.date between '2016-09-07 23:59:00' and '2016-09-14 23:59:00'
   group by v.Consultant,User.colorcode
```

Answer (score -1):

I beleive you can just group by multiple columns and use an aggregate function on the marketing_fee column.

```
select v.Consultant, SUM(a.marketing_fee), user.colorcode 
from valuations v 
join status_history sh on sh.ref = v.Ref join 
user on user.username = v.Consultant 
join answer a on a.title = v.Ref 
where sh.status = 'booked' and sh.date between '2016-09-07 23:59:00' and '2016-09-14 23:59:00'
group by v.consultant, a.marketing_fee, user.colorcode
```

Comment: That doesnt work it still has multiple consultants and one of the collumn names is SUM(a.markerting_fee) is that because its mysql